Using vision enhancement in GPT4 with vision API
I am trying to use the GPT4 with vision model and using the vision and grounding enhancement. How do i know if response has been processed using the vision enhancement? I am not able to get the bounding box details of the object in the response.
API used is
https://{RESOURCE_NAME}.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{DEPLOYMENT_NAME}/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-12-01-preview

{
    "enhancements": {
            "ocr": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "grounding": {
              "enabled": true
            }
    },
    "data_sources": [
    {
        "type": "AzureComputerVision",
        "parameters": {
            "endpoint": "<computer_vision_endpoint>",
            "key": "<computer_vision_key>"
        }
    }],
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Describe this picture:"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image_url",
                    "image_url": {
                        "url":"<image URL>" 
                    }
                }
           ] 
        }
    ],
    "max_tokens": 100, 
    "stream": false 
}

I was expecting bounding box details in the response but not getting the same.
